# Asp.net dropdown onchange calling function and within function getting dropdown selected values

Tags: javascript, c#

1.aspx page

```
A.) asp:dropdown ...onchange="javascriptfunctionname">

B.) <script>
Javascriptfunctionname
{
  Getting dropdown selected values
}
</script>


C.) Problem Here:
How to pass drop down selected values in any c# method


D.) C# code
Public methodname
{
     // NEED TO COMBO VALUES HERE ON CALLING ONCHANGE FUNCTION
}
```

Please help to guide.Its very important and is to complete urgently.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use post back on the control, and everytime onchange hit, it will do postback to server and you may get your value on the server side.

html

```
<asp:dropdownlist runat="server" autopostback="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged" id="ddlTest">  </asp:dropdownlist>
```

code behind

```
protected void ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedText = ddlTest.SelectedItem.Text;
        string selectedValue = ddlTest.SelectedItem.Value;

        //--- Show results in page.
        Response.Write("Selected Text is " + selectedText + " and selected value is :" + selectedValue);
    }
```

Comment: Before i followed the above steps. But again for me a problem to pass parameter with the method:protected void ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){    methodname(dropdownvalues)   }

Comment: methodname(dropdownvalues){     dataset ;  .....  return serializer.Serialize(rows);     }

Comment: javascript:  function initialize(){       var velocity = JSON.parse('<%=methodname() %>');  //PROBLEM IS HOW TO PASS PARAMETER IN THIS METHODNAME. Please help

Comment: im not so sure what are you trying to achive.